# `pip install` from Github private repo with `setup.py` not in `root` directory

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setup.py

Our current setup is this:

- `repo_1`
- `repo_2`
- `components_repo`

`repo_1` and `repo_2` both need to make use of the components from the `component_repo` and all 3 repo's are in Github.

The `component_repo` folder structure is like this:

```
.
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── setup.py
    ├── folder_1
    │   ├── functions.py
    ├── folder_2
    │   ├── functions.py
```

So I looked into "installing" this `component_repo` and found these docs:

- [private python packages](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/private-python-packages.html)
- [vcs support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#vcs-support)

and they both explain how to use this command:

```
python -m pip install -e git+https://$GITHUB_USER:$GH_TOKEN@github.com/$GITHUB_USER/components.git@main#egg=common&subdirectory=src
```

But then, I get this error:

> ERROR: components from
> git+https://$GITHUB_USER:****@github.com/$GITHUB_USER/components.git@main#egg=common
> does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor
> 'pyproject.toml' found.

And I see this in my `repo_1` `src` folder:

[image]

So as I understand, it will do a `git clone`, then build with `setup.py` and then remove the cloned repo. But it's failing at step 2 and not completing the final step (I think).

Admittedly, I still don't quite understand what needs to be used for `#egg=` but I do know, if I exclude `#egg=[whatever]` from the command, then I get this error:

> ERROR: Could not detect requirement name for
> 'git+https://$GITHUB_USER:$GH_TOKEN@github.com/$GITHUB_USER/components.git@main',
> please specify one with #egg=your_package_name

I figured that with using the `&subdirectory=src` in the command, I am specifying the location of the `setup.py` file, but it turns out, that's not the case.

So I thought I would move the `setup.py` file one directory up, to be in the root directory instead, and lo and behold, it works. I did need to update the paths inside the `setup.py` file for it to work (since I am one directory higher), but it worked.

Comment: Depending on your shell, you might need to add double quotes around that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your shell, you might need to add double quotes around that URL, otherwise `#` and/or `&` might be interpreted by the shell:

```
python -m pip install -e "git+https://$GITHUB_USER:$GH_TOKEN@github.com/$GITHUB_USER/components.git@main#egg=common&subdirectory=src"
```

Comment: Thank you! :) And FYI for anyone else, I am using `zsh`, so I needed the double-quotes around the git URL.